# Wait response for HTTP request using NSURLSession - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, request

Right now I am developing I little class that has a method for sending a POST request. This method is intended for returning a ResponseModel (which basically has two ivars: code, message), this model is going to be map from response.
I am using `dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:` method. Like this:

```
+ (void)sendPOSTRequest1:(id)data withResponse:(void (^) (ResponseModel * data) )taskResponse {
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [self getRequestObject];

    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSData * requestData = [self encodeAndEncrypt:data];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];


    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session
                                      dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                      completionHandler:
                                      ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

        ResponseModel * responseModel = [NSKeyedUnarchiver
                                         unarchivedObjectOfClass:[ResponseModel class]
                                         fromData:data
                                         error:&error];

        taskResponse(responseModel);


    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

**And call the method this way:**

```
DummyModel * dummy = [[DummyModel alloc] init];

__block ResponseModel * result = [[ResponseModel alloc] init];

[HTTPRequest sendPOSTRequest1:dummy withResponse:^(ResponseModel *data) {
    result =  data;
    NSLog(@"data %@",data);
}];

// It`s not sure that the asyncronous request has already finished by this point
NSLog(@"POST result : %@",result);
```

My problem is that I do not want to execute a code in call back block because I need to wait for the response in order to return a ResponseModel and whoever is implementing this can receive the Model and make other stuff.
I been researching for using NSURLConnection because it has a method for executing Synchronous request, but now It´s deprecated, so I been wondering: is It a way I can wait for a response using what I have in the code ?

Comment: No, you invariably don’t want to wait. Whomever is calling your `sendPOSTRequest` method should adopt the exact same asynchronous patterns that you have here (e.g. completion blocks, etc.). I know, it feels like it would be so sensible and easy if you made this a synchronous method that just returned the value, but it is almost always the exact opposite of what one should do. And, as you point out, you don’t want to use the deprecated `NSURLConnection` either. There’s a reason the new API doesn’t offer synchronous methods, so embrace the asynchronous patterns.

Comment: Hi, @Rob, thank you for your answer. So, now that you mention to attatch to this Asynchornous pattern, Is it still posible to handle some UI interaction inside the block (when method is being called) in order to retrieve information to the user ?

Comment: Yep, you can do that in the completion handler block that you pass to `sendPOSTRequest`. The only trick is that you’d just want to that block dispatch ivar and UI updates back to the main queue, e.g. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GCD to implement synchronous request like this:

swift code

```swift
public static func requestSynchronousData(request: URLRequest) -> Data? {
    var data: Data? = nil
    let semaphore: DispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
        taskData, _, error -> () in
        data = taskData
        if data == nil, let error = error {print(error)}
        semaphore.signal()
    })
    task.resume()
    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
    return data
}
```

Objective-C code

```
+ (NSData *)requestSynchronousData:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    __block NSData * data = nil;
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable taskData, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
        data = taskData;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    [task resume];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    return data;
}
```

You can use dispatch_async to handle UI interaction inside the block

```
DummyModel * dummy = [[DummyModel alloc] init];

__block ResponseModel * result = [[ResponseModel alloc] init];

[HTTPRequest sendPOSTRequest1:dummy withResponse:^(ResponseModel *data) {
    result =  data;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // handle some ui interaction
    });
    NSLog(@"data %@",data);
}];
```